# Kubernetes change cipher for certificates

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kube-apiserver

I have been poring over links related to kubeadm to try and change the cipher on my Kubernetes cluster certificate. The problem is that I need to disable DES/3DES so that this command will fail:

```
openssl s_client -connect IP:2379 -cipher "DES:3DES" -tls1_2
```

Some of the links I've looked through so far (if I list them all, this post will get too long):

- [SSL Vulnerability Sweet32](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/10354) (how this all started)
- [kube-apiserver configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/)
- [12 Kubernetes configuration best practices](https://www.stackrox.com/post/2019/09/12-kubernetes-configuration-best-practices/)
- [kubeadm alpha certs renew all](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-alpha/#cmd-certs-renew)

I was hoping that changing the `kube-apiserver` configuration to use these flags (in the `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` file) would help, but it did not (pardon typos, I cannot copy/paste out of the client I have to use):

```
...
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - ...
    - --tls-cipher-suites=TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    - --tls-min-version=VersionTLS12
    image: k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.18.6
...
```

I could manually regenerate all the certificates in `/etc/kubernetes/pki` following [these guidelines](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/certificates/), but I am hoping to stick with the `kubeadm` or other Kubernetes-provided tools to auto-handle it. I can't find any documentation on manually generating each file on my own that is set up for people completely new to the administration.

Help, links, suggestions, etc. are appreciated! I'm not allowed to use the cluster or even demonstrate functionality to people until this is done, unfortunately.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve. Could you please tell us what is the ultimate goal of your use case? Do you want to disable/change some of the etcd certs?

Comment: @OhHiMark I am willing to bet that his security team at his organization is flagging these vulnerabilities and or he is proactively attempting to harden his Kubernetes environment.

Comment: @OhHiMark what metallica1973 said - that's the exact scenario

Answer (score 7):

In our vanilla kubernetes 1.18.3 installation on Ubuntu 16.04 setup with kubeadm we solved this the following:

kubelets (port 10250):
in File `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml` add this:

```
tlsCipherSuites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
```

restart the kubelet.service via `systemctl restart kubelet.service`

kube-api-server (port 6443):
in File `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` add a additional array entry in `spec.containers.command`

```
- --tls-cipher-suites=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Delete the pod kube-apiserver in namespace kube-system if necessary.

edit: don't created a e.g. backupfile from `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` in the same directory. kube-api-server will apply this backupfile as well.

Comment: I will give it a shot again to see if that does the trick. I think I may had the placement of that in wrong spot. Did you place it under, "Specs" ?

Comment: Yes. As parameter of the `command:` array. 
It worked on my 1.18.x Cluster. But on 1.17.x I still have it under investigation. 
Please post your feedback.

Comment: Using Kubes v.1.15, it didnt work. Still digging around and will provide feedback ASAP

Comment: I think its deeper then we thought in how Kubes handles ciphers: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/81145 and                                             
https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/9496. It appears that by default Kubes uses HTTP2 and is picky with what ciphers it wants use for certain versions. It looks like Kubes 1.18 will provide greater flexibility in this area

Comment: Apologies for the late response (thanks, covid-19) - I haven't had success, but I was able to convince the admins that with Kubernetes behind multiple firewalls that it's OK. Nothing failed the penetration tests, but it fails the scans.  @schmichri - I am trying to figure out your suggestion as a parameter of the `command:` array.

Comment: I just stumpled about this. I had backupfiles (created by ansible) of `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` named `kube-apiserver.yaml.11563.2020-08-06@10:03:32~` which avoided that the kube-api-server was configured correctly. As soon I've deleted the backupfiles the api-server took the correct settings

Comment: @metallica1973 what output do you have on the control-plane node shell with `ps aux | grep api ` ? Do you see the --tls-cipher-suites=TLS_ECDHE... parameter?